# Can't find the reason why a question has been closed

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering why this question was closed:

https://serverfault.com/questions/496129/downloading-a-large-file-stops-all-network-activity-from-that-disk

I couldn't find anything wrong with it when comparing with the FAQ. Can someone explain why it was closed?

I'm not challenging the decision I'm just interested in the reasons as I seem unable to deduce them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with the close reason, it's would be on-topic, if he gave enough details to make it a real question (I would have closed as NARQ). While he does a terrible job describing the issue, I can at least get the gist of the problem. There's not nearly enough detail about his server to give a reasonable explanation or fix however.